# Почему идет замедление работы программы при распараллеливание программы на ryzen 5 2600

Tags: оптимизация, openmp

Построил график распараллеливание программы, программы DGEMV на OpenMP(умножение матрицы на вектор, размеры матрицы 15000х15000, 20000х20000, 25000х25000). Почему когда распараллеливание идет до 6 потока, speedup увеличивается(время ускорения программы относительно однопоточной работы), а при 8 потоках идет снижение? Процессор ryzen 5 2600x[image: о]

Comment: Потому что ваш процессор - шестиядерный

Comment: Но указано, что у него есть 12 потоков, это не играет роли?

Comment: А Hyperthreading включен? В Диспетчере задач сколько ядер отображается?

Comment: Гипертрединг способен оптимизировать далеко не все задачи

Comment: @Rumeone Hyperthreading по сути на одном ядре выполняет по очереди инструкции то из одного потока, то из другого, в итоге количество тактов достающихся одному потоку, если ядро полностью загружено оказывается в 2 раза меньше. Оно оптимизирует только то, что контекста 2 и не надо их переключать.

Comment: То есть максимальное ускорение программы будет тогда, когда на 1 ядре будет выполняться инструкции из 1 потока? Допустим процессор 6 ядерный и 12 потоков, значит наилучшее ускорение будет когда на каждое ядро по 1 потоку будет задействовано?

Comment: @Rumeone Ну тут есть пара нюансов, что если 2 потока делают совершенно разные вещи и им нужны разные блоки исполнения процессора, то что то они и в параллель сделают. Но когда у вас потоки ведут интенсивные расчеты и вдобавок по одному алгоритму, то они в любом случае на одном ядре друг друга держат. Плюс к этому могут быть разные эффекты с кешем. Так что да, для вашей задачи оптимальным будет рассчитывать на количество физических ядер.